# AngularJs Serialize form data without using ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

Before I continue to my question, I know ho to get form data inside `AngularJs` using `ngModel`, but it's giving some problems since everytime users interact with the form it will run the *digest cycle*, which can cause some performance problems in some areas of my application.

I know I can have "some" control over this by using `ngModelOption`, but it's not something simple to use, since I would need to apply it for each `ngModel` inside the form. At least I don't know another way to go over this situation.

---

Basically what I need is to have a simple form, doesn't need to update anything immediately (think about a login form, user registration, for example, where we just need to collect the data and send to the database).

As simple as this:

```
<form name="loginForm" novalidate ng-submit="loginForm.$valid && vm.login()">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
    <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

But without all the events used inside AngularJs, which will fire the digestCycle, go over other areas, etc..

> Note: I can just use AngularJs (or pure JS) to do this.

Comment: then how will you validate your form? try writing jQuery for those!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to use [jQuery (not just jqLite)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). Then you can do this to serialize a form

html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" novalidate ng-submit="loginForm.$valid && vm.login()">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
        <button type='button' ng-click="LogIn()">Login</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

script

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.LogIn = function()
    console.log(angular.element('#loginForm').serialize());//Check
});
```

Comment: isn't it possible using just jqLite?

Comment: I don't think `.serialize()` is available in the lite version.. but worth a shot..